# Dynamically update image using Python Flask AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, get, flask, jinja2

I have 1 very simple web application I am building right now but am very new to flask and jinja (and web development as a whole actually).

I have a watch folder, which will be getting an image sent to it via ftp on a pulse for ever. This wtch folder will only ever have one image in. Every 1 minute, the old image is replaced by a new image, with a new timestamp.

I would like to dynamically update the page, (and displayed timestamp) on a pulse as well, without having to reload any banners or static images that I will add later. I only want to update the following two lines out of the "Channels.Jinja" sample to follow.

```
    <br>{{screenshot_datetime}}<br/>
    <img src={{screenshot_location}} width="100%"/>
```

## Channels.Jinja

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Training</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor=white>
 <div id=main>
 <br>Date and Time of Screenshot <br/>
 <br>{{screenshot_datetime}}<br/>
 <img src={{screenshot_location}} width="100%"/>
 </div>

 <div id='test'>
<p>
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){get_image()},1000);

function get_image() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'get_data',
    success: function({{data}}) {
    $('img').attr('src', data);  
    }
    });
}
</script>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Channels.py

```
 def render_channel_route(cr):
 static_folder = os.path.join('static',cr)
file_list = os.listdir(static_folder)

channel_files = [f for f in file_list if f.startswith(cr)]

if not channel_files :
    logger.error('Could not find image file for Channel. File should start with {0}'.format(cr))
    abort(404)
img = os.path.join(static_folder,file_list[0])

ts = get_time_from_filename(file_list[0],cr)

return render_template('Channels.jinja',screenshot_datetime=time.strftime('%c',ts),screenshot_location=img)



@app.route('/channel01-10')
def first_tab():
return render_channel_route('channel01-10')


@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
   return render_template('Channels.jinja',
 screenshot_datetime=time.strftime('%c',ts),screenshot_location=img)
```

Im at a loss, Ive been bumbling around for a while now. Any and all advice is welcome! I am seeing a 304 response upon refresh, but not even the timer i am trying to put on it is working. Pardon sloppy code, highly volatile code is getting changed often -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it there is a "special" way to deal with Ajax using some Flask extension, but in the "normal" Ajax flow first you need to use url_for to put the correct url in your Ajax call and return the data formatted in some way (in my example in JSON) and not to render the template again:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: "{{ url_for('get_data') }}", 
    success: function(resp){
        $('img').attr('src', resp.url);
        $('#sst').html(resp.time);
    }
});
```

So, in your get_data function in your controller you have to get the time and the path again for your image an then return some like this (to fit in my example before):

```
from flask import json
@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    #get time and path
    time=... 
    path=... 
    return json.dumps({time:time,url:path}), 200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

Look that I use $('#sst') so you have to put in your HTML:

```
<br><span id='sst'>{{screenshot_datetime}}</span><br/>
```

Comment: Im still struggling to get it to work right now. I am going to have 8 or so channels so each /get_data call will need a referene to the channel, aka the "cr" variable. in render_channel_route. I am not sure how to serve the img location (which should be osmething like \static\channel01-10\channel01-10_timestamp.png    since I will need to parse the filename to get the timestamp and filename (since this is watch folder I dont control naming). I tried adding the code you suggested but I havent progressed. need pulse requestI will need to investigate furhter tomorrow, so thank you for the input!

Comment: To send the channels' number (for example) to the get_data function you can pass it as a query string. If you know the channel number when jinja2 renders you can use `{{ url_for('get_data', channel=03) }} ` and if you get the channel number in a more dynamic way you can use `'{{ url_for('get_data') }}' + '?channel=' + your_channel_var_set_somewere`. And of course, in your controller to get the query you have to use the Flask request object: `ct_number = request.args.get('channel', None)`.